# PHP mail function: delivering mail to webmail (official mail-id) but not delivering mail to yahoo and gmail

Tags: php, mysql

The Below code is to send to forgotted password to the user mail.
**The mail is delivering only to webmail ie(official Email ID) and not delivering  to Yahoo mail id and gmail id.**
I dont know where i made a mistake please help me

```
<?php
session_start();  // Start Session
//Connect to the database through our include 
    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
session_register("session");
// This is displayed if all the fields are not filled in
$empty_fields_message = "<p>Please go back and complete all the fields in the form.</p>Click <a class=\"two\" href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">here</a> to go back";
// Convert to simple variables  
$email = $_POST['email'];
if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {

?>
<?php
}
elseif (empty($email)) {
    echo $empty_fields_message;
}
else {
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$status = "OK";
$msg="";
//error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR);
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
$msg="Your email address is not correct<BR>"; 
$status= "NOTOK";}

echo "<br><br>";
if($status=="OK"){  $query="SELECT email,username FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";

$st=mysql_query($query) or die("Database error");
$recs=mysql_num_rows($st);
$row=mysql_fetch_object($st);
$em=$row->email;// email is stored to a variable
 if ($recs == 0) {
//Redirect to denied page.
 print "<script language='Javascript'>document.location.replace('forgotenpass_denied.php');</script>";
}
function makeRandomPassword() { 
          $salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789"; 
          srand((double)microtime()*1000000);  
          $i = 0; 
          while ($i <= 7) { 
                $num = rand() % 33; 
                $tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1); 
                $pass = $pass . $tmp; 
                $i++; 
          } 
          return $pass; 
    } 
    $random_password = makeRandomPassword();  
    $password = md5($random_password); 

    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password='$password'  WHERE email='$email'"); 

    $to = "$email";
    $from = "geetha.victor@tryteksolutions.com";
    $subject = "Your Password Has been reset"; 
    $message = "Hi, we have reset your password. 

    Your New Password is: $random_password 

    http://www.trytek.tryteksolutions.co.in/login.php
    Once logged in you can change your password 

    Thanks! 
    Admin 

    This is an automated response, DO NOT REPLY!"; 

        $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $to = "$to";
        // Finally send the activation email to the member
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    print "<script language='Javascript'>document.location.replace('forgotenpass_sucess.php');</script>"; 
 } 
 else {echo "<center><font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red >$msg <br><br><input type='button' value='Retry' onClick='history.go(-1)'></center></font>";}
}
?>
```

Comment: You may want to check your mailserver's logs for the reason it fails.

Comment: @Maerlyn may i know How to check mailserver's logs for yahoo and gmail ID